# Change or remove default style in GeoServer tiles layers

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, tile-layer

I have publish vector tiles layers in GeoServer. It's displaying with default style as shown in image [image]

and

[image].

I want to change style for vector tiles in GeoServer.

Comment: I thought the whole point of vector tiles was that the client was in charge of the styling

Comment: from client end we change like using open layers.But cant we customize style like wms layer